# Julia package install fail with Please specify by known `name=uuid`

Tags: julia

I have an error when trying to install any Julia package:

```
Pkg.add("Combinatorics")
   Cloning default registries into `~/.julia`
   Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
     Added registry `General` to `~/.julia/registries/General`
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * Logging (56ddb016-857b-54e1-b83d-db4d58db5568 in manifest but not in project)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.
```

What can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could fix this problem after the following two steps:

First: (not sure if absolutely needed)

```
rm(joinpath(homedir(), ".julia", "registries"); recursive=true)
```

Second: installing the package mentioned as missing in the error message:

```
Pkg.add("Logging")
 Resolving package versions...
 Installed MappedArrays ─────────── v0.2.2
 Installed IntervalSets ─────────── v0.3.2
 Installed PDMats ───────────────── v0.9.10
 Installed ColorVectorSpace ─────── v0.7.1
 etc
```

Then my Pkg install worked:

```
Pkg.add("Combinatorics")
 Resolving package versions...
 Installed Polynomials ─ v0.6.0
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.1/Project.toml`
  [861a8166] + Combinatorics v1.0.0
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.1/Manifest.toml`
  [861a8166] + Combinatorics v1.0.0
  [f27b6e38] + Polynomials v0.6.0

julia> using Combinatorics
[ Info: Precompiling Combinatorics [861a8166-3701-5b0c-9a16-15d98fcdc6aa]
```